# Java program establishing data connection got terminated on its own

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I tried the below program to connect to a database and  to pull out data from it . which i can store later as CSV. When i run the program, the process javaw.exe got terminated on its own after some time. could you please advise how i can overcome this and can run it till the end . please find the snippet below

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class myLogin{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String url = "";

 String queryString;
 String temp;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbcx.SybDriver");
        System.out.println("got it");
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
      System.out.println("Failed to load sybase driver.");
      return;
    }
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");

        Statement select = con.createStatement();
        queryString=" ";
        select.executeQuery(queryString);
        ResultSet myResultSet = select.executeQuery(queryString);
        System.out.println("Got results:");
        String m="details.csv";
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(m,false);

        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));

        while(myResultSet.next()) {
            int ncols = myResultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

            for (int i=1; i<(ncols+1); i++) {
                System.out.print(myResultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName (i));
                if (i<ncols) System.out.print(","); else System.out.println();
            }

            do {
                for (int i=1; i<(ncols+1); i++) {
                    out.append(myResultSet.getString(i));
                    System.out.print(myResultSet.getString(i));
                    if (i<ncols) System.out.print(","); else System.out.println();
                }
            } while (myResultSet.next());
        }
        select.close();
        con.close();
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code; doing so will increase readability.

Comment: Did you get the stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

`javaw.exe` is the "Windows" version of `java.exe`.  Basically this creates a process that does not require or output to the console.

If you run `javaw.exe` from the console, it will appear as if nothing has happened (the command will return almost immediately)

Try, instead, running `java.exe` to run your program in the console.

Comment: i cant understand you. i am doing this in eclipse and i got the output printing to console terminated.

Comment: Basically, from your description, you are attempting to run a "console" application using a "windows" process (that has no UI). Can you post the output then?

Comment: What about the file, did it get created??

Comment: sorry i cant post the output. its some sensitive data.The above just prints to console , when i tried with small resultset its fine, the console gets printed. but for large output, the process got terminated and i dont got the stack trace.

Comment: i changed the code to  create and write into a file  but  file just got created and output is not getting written into the file.

Comment: Make sure you call `fos.flush()` and `fos.close()` when you're done writing.  This is best done in the `finally` section of the `try/catch` block to make sure they get called

Comment: Thanks. but the csv is getting generated when i tried getting from sysprocedures but not getting written for some other tables

Comment: Try writing a header to the file as well, to make sure not just the table without data...